# Is it possible to directly upload images captured by camera to Firebase Storage?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I'm using React.js to create an application that would take a photo and upload it to Firebase Storage. I am using the react-webcam library, which uses this command to take a photo:

```
const ImageSrc = webcamRef.current.getScreenshot();
```

This is how I tried uploading the photo to Storage:

```
 storage.ref(`/images`).put(imageSrc)
 .on("state_changed" , alert("success") , alert)
```

However, the file that is uploaded is undefined (no photo).

I tried to construct an URL of the photo using blob:

```
const imageUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(webcamRef.current.getScreenshot()))
```

But I get this error: >Failed to construct 'Blob': The provided value cannot be converted to a sequence.

In the library it is stated that *getScreenshot - Returns a base64 encoded string of the current webcam image.* So, I tried to use the atob command, but I get the error: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded.

Does anyone know how I could upload the image to Firebase Storage? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of blob, try using `putString()` command like this:

`` const task = firebase.storage().ref(`/images`).putString(imageSrc, 'data_url') ``

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#upload_from_a_string), if you want to upload from a Base64url formatted string, you need to call the `putString()` method as follows *(example from the doc)*:

```
var message = '5b6p5Y-344GX44G-44GX44Gf77yB44GK44KB44Gn44Go44GG77yB';
ref.putString(message, 'base64url').then((snapshot) => {
  console.log('Uploaded a base64url string!');
});
```

In your case, since `getScreenshot()` returns a base64 encoded string,  it would be something like:

```
const imageSrc = webcamRef.current.getScreenshot();
storage.ref(`/images`).putString(imageSrc, 'imgBase64')   
 .on("state_changed" , alert("success") , alert)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could I then still be able to use the Cloud Vision API (if photo is base64 encoded)?

Comment: I tried the code, but it doesn't upload anything to Firebase Storage (I also don't get the alert). I get this error in the console: Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: An unknown error occurred, please check the error payload for server response. (storage/unknown)

Comment: Try to catch the error as shown in the doc for [`on()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.storage.UploadTask#on).

Comment: I tried implementing the code like this: const task = firebase.storage().ref(`/images`).putString(imageSrc, 'imgBase64')  
  task.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED, next,
    error,
    complete), however, I still have the same error as before.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution because I am getting the same error as you ?